# Laravel 4 - Iterate through arrays and get values into blade

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am using `etrepat/baum` and I am retrieving all the children for a root category with:

```
$children = $category->children()->get();
```

Then in order to retrieve all of the products that are stored under children categories, I am doing a foreach loop to get the id's for the children categories and another foreach to store the products in a `$children_products[]` array, like so:

```
// store the ids of the children categories
foreach ($children as $child) {
     $children_ids[] = $child->id;
}

// store the products that children categories have
foreach($children_ids as $val) {
     $children_products[] = Product::where('category_id', '=', $val)->get();
}
```

Then I am sending the `$children_products` array to the view to render the results. Although, this is rendering as different arrays for each subcategory that either has products or is empty.

```
[] [{"id":1,"category_id":21,"brand_id":1,"title":"test","description":"Etiam aliquam sem ac velit feugiat elementum. Nunc eu elit velit, nec vestibulum nibh. Curabitur ultrices, diam non ullamcorper blandit, nunc lacus ornare nisi, egestas rutrum magna est id nunc. Pellentesque imperdiet malesuada quam, et rhoncus eros auctor eu. Nullam vehicula metus ac lacus rutrum nec fermentum urna congue. Vestibulum et risus at mi ultricies sagittis quis nec ligula. Suspendisse dignissim dignissim luctus.","price":"1000.00","availability":1,"image":"img\/products\/2014-11-24-14:29:33-00064736.jpg","created_at":"2014-11-24 14:29:34","updated_at":"2014-11-24 14:29:34"}] [] [] [] [] []
```

Is there a way to iterate through these arrays and get the products stored inside the arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably simplify your Product query:

```
$children_products = Product::whereIn('category_id', $children->lists('id'))->get();
```

Then maybe just iterate over the value in Blade?

```
@foreach ($children_products as $product)
{{ $product->title }}
@endforeach
```